# How to render model from blender on frontend?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a skeleton model made in blender. how to display it on the frontend and send information about the selected bone to the backend? Are there ready-made libraries for rendering the model?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130748/how-to-render-a-blender-model-in-a-web-page

Comment: Have a look at `react three fiber` it's a pretty good library for rendering models etc